# Lazy instantiation before or inside of a loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, optimization, lazy-loading

I'm trying to implement lazy instantiation within my code to speed up my app. My question is, when dealing with a for loop, should I create an object right before the loop begins, or within the loop, basically should I do this:

```
NSPredicate *pred= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self LIKE %@", filter];
for(NSString* str in myArray){
//do stuff
}
```

or this:

```
for(NSString* str in myArray){
//do stuff
NSPredicate *pred= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self LIKE %@", filter];
//do stuff that needs this variable
}
```

My thoughts were to do the first one, but a friend says the 2nd one, although isn't the 2nd one creating the object everytime you go through the loop so it's more costly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither one of these is truly lazy:

- The first one creates the predicate even when the loop does not need to execute at all
- The second one is optimal only when the loop executes once; otherwise, throw-away instances of `NSPredicate` get created.

If you wish to stay truly lazy, you could add a condition around the first code example to check that `myArray` is not empty. You could also use a conditional expression, like this:

```
NSPredicate *pred= myArray.count ? [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self LIKE %@", filter] : nil;
```

This is not particularly readable, though, so I would recommend staying with your first approach, which is optimal when the loop is entered at least once.

Answer (score 0):

Well, lazy instantiation would look something like this I think...

```
NSPredicate *pred = nil;

for (NSString *string in myArray) {
    // do stuff...

    // if predicate is required
    if (!pred) {
        pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self LIKE %@", filter];
    }
    // use pred
}
```

But out of the three options. I'd use your first method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much of a choice, with the first way being both clean and simple.  The equivalent alternative is actually:

```
NSPredicate *pred = nil;
for (NSString* str in myArray){
    if (!pred)
        pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self LIKE %@", filter];
    //do stuff
}
```

Which is clearly more complicated than it needs to be.

I would also argue that this isn't really lazy initialization, which really relates to initialization of instance variables at some point after object creation.